# Is MySQL Replication out of sync? Waiting for the slave SQL thread to free enough relay log space

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

MySQL slave server was showing `Waiting for the slave SQL thread to free enough relay log space` status for about a week because the relay logs were full.

It happened because the SQL Thread was stuck on an error. Once I cleared the error, it started processing relay logs again and freeing space.

Does this mean that the Slave will be out of sync with master, even after reading through all all the relay logs?

My reasoning is that since the slave couldn't download any relay logs for a week, that data would be lost.

Please clarify to me what's going on, so I can determine whether or not to resync servers. Re-syncing slave with master is not my favorite option since the database is huge.

Answer (score 0):

Try running some `select` queries on the slave, which should return some data recently inserted in the master.  If replication has stopped, the new data will not be in the slave.